# How to resolve the following error and exception in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

**i m working on the fragment it show following errors and exception ...at run time..help me out to resolve these error and eception ** and emulator also show message ui has stopped..i m new in android programming...

```
enter code here04-06 11:45:03.251: I/dalvikvm(707): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-06 11:45:03.420: I/dalvikvm(707): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-06 11:45:03.671: D/AndroidRuntime(707): Shutting down VM
04-06 11:45:03.671: W/dalvikvm(707): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
04-06 11:45:03.691: I/dalvikvm(707): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
  ComponentInfo{com.example.android.fragments/com.example.android.fragments.MainActivity}:  
                      android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
            04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at         
           android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)  
        04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at  
                android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
   04-06 11:45:03.731:E/AndroidRuntime(707): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
     04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):     at 
                   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
       04-06 11:45:03.731:E/AndroidRuntime(707):at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 04-06 11:45:03.731:E/AndroidRuntime(707):at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
 04-06 11:45:03.731:E/AndroidRuntime(707):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
  04-06 11:45:03.731:E/AndroidRuntime(707):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 04-06 11:45:03.731:E/AndroidRuntime(707):at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 04-06 11:45:03.731:E/AndroidRuntime(707): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: 
 Error inflating class fragment
 04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):     at 
 android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
      04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):    at 
        android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
      04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):    at  
      android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
         04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):     at 
     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
         04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):     at 
              android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at 

        04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
          04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):    at  
        com.example.android.fragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
        04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
         04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):     at 
      android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
       04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):   at 
            android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
    04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  ... 11 more
    04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet    
       created
    04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at 
   android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
    04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at 
  android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
    04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at     
   com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment.onCreate(HeadlinesFragment.java:107)
    04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at  
   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:834)
      04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):    at 
   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1058)
    04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at   
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1156)
                  04-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):    at 
   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:270)
  4-06 11:45:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):     at           a    
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)

   04-06 11:03.731: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  ... 21 more
   04-06 11:45:03.781: I/dalvikvm(707): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
   04-06 11:45:04.201: I/dalvikvm(707): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
      04-06 11:45:04.241: I/dalvikvm(707): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
        04-06 11:45:04.351: I/dalvikvm(707): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
       04-06 11:45:04.361: I/dalvikvm(707): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
      04-06 11:45:20.781: I/Process(707): Sending signal. PID: 707 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment**

You have error in your XML file at line 23 which u are using in your MainActivity.

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created**

The reason for the error is may be you are trying to find views that haven't been created yet.

The life cycle for a fragment is (source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)